# Two popups dont work properly

Tags: jquery, html, css

I can include one popup into my site, but when I want to add second this don't work properly.

I'm looking for two buttons with individual popup for each,.

[check Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/24A9b/7224/) and [here plugin offical site](http://dinbror.dk/blog/bPopup/)

What's wrong with this?

**JQUERY**

```
(function ($) {
     $(function () {
          $('#my-button,#my-button2').bind('click', function (e) {
               e.preventDefault();
               $('#element_to_pop_up,#element_to_pop_up2').bPopup();
           });
       });
 })(jQuery);
```

**CSS**

```
#element_to_pop_up {
   background-color:#fff;
   border-radius:15px;
   color:#000;
   display:none;
   padding:20px;
   min-width:400px;
   min-height: 180px;
}

.b-close {
   cursor:pointer;
   position:absolute;
   right:10px;
   top:5px;
};

#element_to_pop_up2 {
background-color: black;
border-radius:15px;
color:#000;
display:none;
padding:20px;
min-width:400px;
min-height: 180px;
```

}

**HTML**

```
<button id="my-button">POP IT UP</button>
<div id="element_to_pop_up"> <a class="b-close">x<a/>
Content of popup
</div>

<button id="my-button">POP IT UP</button>
<div id="element_to_pop_up2"> <a class="b-close">x<a/>
Content of popup
</div>
```

Comment: you have a messy code there

Comment: I suspect that if you're not going to spend the time to ask your question and format in a manner which can be read, you're not going to get an answer.

Comment: I'm wondering what you are expecting to happen by showing two popups in same time?!

Comment: I need do it fast, that's why I didnt spend a lot of time for trying format it properly. In the same time? definitly no...

Comment: I update all files.. sory some bug with my fiddle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uh.. seems like this is what you want.

```
<button id="my-button" class="popBtn" data-toggle-pop="element_to_pop_up">POP IT UP</button>
<div id="element_to_pop_up"> <a class="b-close">x<a/>
Content of popup
</div>

<button id="my-button2" class="popBtn" data-toggle-pop="element_to_pop_up2">POP IT UP</button> <!-- You put my-button in your code -->
<div id="element_to_pop_up2"> <a class="b-close">x<a/>
Content of popup
</div>
```

JS:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.popBtn').click(function() {
        var target = $(this).attr('data-toggle-pop');
        $('#' + target).bPopup();
    });
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HSCwC/

Answer (score 3):

You are not using code with good way.

I just change for easy way.

```
<button class="my-button" data-rel="element_to_pop_up">POP IT UP</button>
<div id="element_to_pop_up"> <a class="b-close">x<a/>
    Content of popup
</div>
<button class="my-button" data-rel="element_to_pop_up2">POP IT UP</button>
<div id="element_to_pop_up2" >
    <a class="b-close">x<a/>
    Content of popup2
</div>
```

I added the **class and data-rel** attribute.

```
(function ($) {

        $('.my-button').bind('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var result_div = $(this).data('rel')
            $('#'+result_div).bPopup();
        });


})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 $('#my-button').bind('click', function (e) {

            e.preventDefault();

            $('#element_to_pop_up1').bPopup();
            $('#element_to_pop_up2').bPopup();

 });
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/24A9b/7223/)